# Data integrity in concurrent requests from a user to a Spring MVC Controller method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, concurrency

I was hoping to understand how one can ensure data integrity in case of concurrent requests from same user to the same Spring Controller method ?

> for e.g.suppose in an Online shopping scenario,a user happens to make
>   concurrent requests to a Controller method
>   (e.g.**'/debitWallet?amount=100'** to deduct his wallet money). The
>   'Wallet' could be a hibernate entity which is obtained in this method
>   through a standard 'WalletService' instance -->'WalletDao' instance.
>   Now how can we ensure data integrity of the wallet for concurrent
>   requests?
>
> - On what objects do I synchronize here?
> - what would be the scope of different beans(service,dao etc.)    although I don't see any way that would help since the Wallet is going to be taken from the data store?
> - Should I even take the Wallet from the DB every-time the Controller method is invoked.Would it be a right approach? Instead should I use @SessionAttribute on this Wallet entity & then use it for every request to this method?

I could really use some help here to understand how to tackle data-integrity issue in this use case?

Comment: how many application servers do you have?

Comment: This is actually just an example I used. I basically wanted to know if Spring MVC framework can help me handle this kind of scenario since its a web application framework. If so, how?....I mean,it can be a likely scenario for a user using multiple browser windows,right.

Comment: for argument sake, let's say I am using a single Tomcat server

Comment: If you are going to scale your app servers horizontally, any kind of instance level synchronization isn't really going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all answer the question: how frequent will be your data changed?

If it is not so frequent (or your database iterations are fast) you can use pattern: "User always operates with recent wallet instance, which is constantly synchronized with database". And to make it work user always sends Optimistick lock value (@Version field on entity), and in case changes happened in background: user receives Optimistick locking exception.

If it is frequent you should deeply analyze your implementation and then - search places for synchronization. Or even rework your API.

Comment: I am not currently facing this issue in my work. I am trying to understand how data-integrity can be ensured in a situation where concurrent requests from same user to same Spring controller method occurs? Does Spring MVC provide a mechanism to tackle this or should this be taken care of in the data-layer, like u have mentioned